# android event handler to trigger event when view is clicked

Tags: android, event-handling, callback, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` that is invisible and becomes visible when a menu option is selected, I'm trying to hide it by setting it's visibility to Invisible when you touch anything that is not in that layout.

I've used an onTouch event handler attched to a `ScrollView` that fills the screen but that only fires after you have moved your finger and doesn't fire on just a tap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On layout add android:clickable="true" and use setOnClickListener()